# Meaning of torque

Tags: torque, moment

So, in the diagram, A is the axis of rotation and the net moment from the forces acting there(as shown) is 6Nm.The moment is due to the forces acting in the direction as shown and the moment the equilateral triangle has a length of 1m.Also, A is the midpoint. Now, what does this 6Nm tell me visually? Does this mean that B experiences a force of 3 N and C experiences a force of 3N?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the magnitude of the individual forces?

Comment: @DavidWhite the force causing anticlockwise moment is 48N and the force causing the clockwise moment is 24N, but, do these forces matter once rotation starts?

Comment: Lime, I was asking because more detail increases the chances of you getting the kind of answer that you are seeking.